# SKAction with Key changes Sprite Behavior

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I've been learning Swift while laid up from back surgery and any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Issue Description:
I have a function that pushes a sprite backwards when hit. When I use

```
self.runAction(jumpBackSequence)
```

I get the desired behavior. (The sprite is pushed back a good distance.)

[image]

Now when I update this to use "withKey" (because I need to be able to stop the forward action again on the next contact the forward movement is greatly dimished.

```
self.runAction(jumpBackSequence, withKey: "moveStraightLine")
```

[image]

My function creating this action is below:

```
 func pushBack(){
            self.removeActionForKey("moveStraightLine")

            let height:CGFloat = 5
            let jumpDistanceA:CGFloat = 20
            let jumpDistanceB:CGFloat = 20
            let duration:NSTimeInterval = 0.15

            let jumpUp = SKAction.moveByX(0, y:height, duration:duration)
            let moveBack = SKAction.moveByX(jumpDistanceA, y: 0, duration: duration)
            let jStep1 = SKAction.group([jumpUp, moveBack])

            let jumpDown = SKAction.moveByX(0, y:(height * -1), duration:duration)
            let moveBack2 = SKAction.moveByX(jumpDistanceB, y: 0, duration: duration)
            let jStep2 = SKAction.group([jumpDown, moveBack2])

            let moveZombie1 = SKAction.moveToX(0, duration: spawnSpeed1()   )
            let removeZombie1 = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            let moveAndRemoveZombie1 = SKAction.sequence([moveZombie1, removeZombie1])

            let jumpBackSequence = SKAction.sequence([jStep1, jStep2, moveAndRemoveZombie1])

            self.runAction(jumpBackSequence)

  //          self.runAction(jumpBackSequence, withKey: "moveStraightLine")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using moveTo, not moveBy, so when you add the action back in to move the zombie, you are now saying starting from the closer spot, take X seconds to move to the end, not take X seconds - the time already travelled.  You do not want this due to the effect you see.  Use moveBy, and the zombie speed will stay consistant

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this behavior happened, but I realized that the runAction withKey was actually moving the code the specified distance where as the example without the key was not.  When I updated the code to use a fraction of screen width it behaves the same with and without a key - which makes me think this might actually be an minor bug in Swift.

To fix the issue I updated the distances to

```
let jumpDistanceA:CGFloat = (self.scene?.size.width)! * 0.15
let jumpDistanceB:CGFloat = (self.scene?.size.width)! * 0.15
```

I hope this helps someone else. 
Best regards,
mpe

Comment: I think because you are removing the action before the time. If you put the key, and remove the line self.removeActionForKey("moveStraightLine") at the top, what's the behavior?

Comment: Many thanks, that key stops the original movement. When I create the sprite I set it moving via an action with the same key.  To make the jump back, I first need to remove that.  Oddly, Updating the code to use a fraction of the screen width did fix it.  I'm not certain if I stumbled on a bug or some deeper swift mystery.  Thank you for taking the time to look and reply.  I'm learning a lot from everyone who has already taken the time to post on stack overflow.

Comment: Why are you using the same name for different action? Try to rename different